# Day and year with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm doing a program which, given the day of the year, estabilishes day and month.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work when the input is >31. 
I hope that someone will help me, thank you.

```
<script>


var dayn=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
var vettmonth=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May","June","July","August","September","October","November","Dicember"];

function f()
    {
    var nday, day, month, count=0;

    nday=eval(ngiorno.value);

    for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
       if (nday>dayn[i]){
          count=count+dayn[i]; }
       else if(nday<32){
          day=nday;
          month=vettmonth[i]; 
          break;
       } 
       else if(nday>31 && nday<dayn[i+1]+count){
          day=nday-count;
          month=vettmonth[i+1]; 
          break;
       } 
    }

    mmese.value=month;
    ggiorno.value=day;      

}
</script>
```

Comment: "_it doesn't work_" Can you explain what actually does happen and why it confuses you? What did you expect to happen that isn't? You should also take the time to correctly format and indent your code before posting.

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`? Use `parseInt()` to convert input to a number.

Comment: @ADyson Most likely, `32 => February 1`

Comment: nday contains a number from 0 to 365. When it is <32 the code works, but when it is >31 the month and the day are "undefined"

Comment: @ADyson He described what it's supposed to do in the first line of the question: Turn a day of the year to a month and day. What's confusing about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're never reducing `nday` as you go through the months. So if `nday > 31`, `nday > dayn[i]` will be true every time, and you'll never execute the `else if` blocks that set `day` and `month`. You need to subtract `dayn[i]` from `nday`.

There's no need for two `else if` blocks. When the `if` block fails you're in the correct month. And the `count` variable is not needed, either.

```js
var dayn = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var vettmonth = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

function f(nday) {
  var day, month;
  var daynum = nday;
  for (var i = 0; i < dayn.length; i++) {
    if (nday > dayn[i]) {
      nday -= dayn[i];
    } else {
      day = nday;
      month = vettmonth[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(`${daynum} = ${month} ${day}`);   
}

f(10)
f(32);
f(150);
f(360);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've made this more complicated then it has to be. You can do something like this:

```js
const vettmonth=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May","June","July","August","September","October","November","Dicember"];


let dayOfTheYear = 120;
let date = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1); // Start of this year
date.setDate(120); // increase the date by "dayOfTheYear"
console.log("Month:",vettmonth[date.getMonth()], "Day:", date.getDate());
```

If you need to do this without using `Date` objects, you can do it like this:

```js
const dayn = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
const vettmonth = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

let dayOfTheYear = 120;
let monthIndex = 0;
let day = 0;

for(let i = 0, sum = 0; i < dayn.length; i++){
  sum+=dayn[i];
  if(dayOfTheYear <= sum){
    monthIndex = i;
    day = (sum - dayOfTheYear) + 1;
    break;
  }
}

console.log("Month:", vettmonth[monthIndex], "Day:", day);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have to do the exercise in that way

Comment: @KingRoy I've included a solution that doesn't use `Date` objects.